# Share source code between php container and nginx container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume

I do a web application with Symfony using Docker images that contain the appplication code. I try to find a way to share source code from the application container and the nginx container.

Actually I use named volume: it's ok for uploaded data, because I want to persist this files between application versions.
But when I use named volume to share source code between containers, it create a conflict when I update the application: data in the named volume is the previous data. Then I'm forced to:

- stop containers
- delete app and nginx containers
- delete the source volume
- then recreate containers with new image that re-create volume and put the new code inside.

Before, we can create the VOLUME in the APP dockerfile and use volumes_from to retrieve the data.

Someone have an idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: How the nginx container proxy to your PHP application and serve static content?

Comment: As I said above, I share the application files with Nginx via a named volume. However, this has a major drawback: at each update of the application, I must remove the named volume (stop 2 containers, remove volume, recreate an empty volume, recreate containers). Because Nginx have acces to all the application files, nginx can serve all assets.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no trivial solution at the time.

If you mount a volume with existing data to a directory it will be overwritten with the volume's content. This behavior is desired by docker developers since volumes are often used as storage for valuable data, and it protects you from losing the data.
There is no option to change this behavior nor any other functionality of docker-compose or docker for this problem.

But you can implement your own solution. One simple way to do that is to run a script which copies your files into a volume which is shared between the both services.

For example, assuming your files are in the `./public` directory and you start the app with the command `app`:

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: nginx
    volumes:
      - assets:/www/data:ro

  web:
    image: my_web_app
    volumes:
      - assets:/assets:rw

volumes:
  assets:
```

Dockerfile

```
...
COPY public ./public
COPY entrypoint.sh ./
CMD ["sh", "./entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```sh
#!/bin/sh
cp -r ./public/* /assets
app
```

This will copy your files into the `/www/data` directory of the nginx-proxy when the application container starts. If you want to copy files even when you run a custom command on the service, change `CMD` to `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: I guess it would also be a good idea to purge the content of the volume when the container starts, so the code would be updated (add, updated, deleted files) when a new image is deployed. What would happen with this solution in the context of Docker Swarm and multiple nodes running the same image ? Each node would copy the files over one another ?

Comment: @MaxiWheat This is an example of a minimalistic solution. It does not replace the mounting function of docker. For instance, it only copies files once upon the start and does not synchonize them. You can of course make a more complex solution which fits your requirements, for instance run `rsync` as a daemon instead of just executing `cp`.